# can swap help a low-memory ZFS server?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, deduplication

If we cannot buy many RAM, can we replace the "missing" RAM with higher amount of SWAP? Ex.: using a dedicated 512 GB SSD for SWAP instead of 512 GB RAM for ZFS with deduplication on an Ubuntu server?

Or it will have such a horrible speed that we shouldn't think of it?

Or NVMe would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

> If we cannot buy many RAM, can we replace the "missing" RAM with higher amount of SWAP?

That's the space of swap space. (No need to capitalize as "SWAP": It's not an acronym. You "swap" out pages.)

> Ex.: using a dedicated 512 GB SSD for SWAP instead of 512 GB RAM for ZFS with deduplication on an Ubuntu server?

If you are building a storage server (I assume that's what you mean with "ZFS with deduplication), then you're adding RAM to make it faster. Replacing the RAM with slow storage again totally ruins the advantage.

ZFS deduplication doesn't *need* 512 GB of RAM – having much RAM just makes it much faster. Otherwise, the deduplication tool will have to use the SSD space (which you already have). That will probably still be more efficient than using swap space.

So, no.

> Or NVMe would be faster?

Makes no sense, NVMe is one of the interfaces SSDs can have. SSD and other mass storage media is orders of magnitude slower than RAM.

> Or it will have such a horrible speed that we shouldn't think of it?

Your ZFS wouldn't even use the swap space, probably, for file system buffers. The whole point of having much RAM in a storage system is that most operations get "handled" by RAM instead of written to storage immediately. You wouldn't gain anything.

Anyway, 512 GB RAM is still a lot of RAM for such an application, and honestly only makes sense in a very high-throughput server with many TB of storage media (we're talking half a petabyte here!). Are you sure you even need that, and if you have that much permanent storage, why is buying RAM a bottleneck? That makes little sense; you will need spares and regular replacement anyway in a system this size, and having more RAM will lower the cost of replacements due to better caching.

I'm sure there's experts on large storage systems here (on unix.SE, or serverfault.SE), but I guess they would, just as me, be a bit confused by the lack of description of the system you're building.