# low-memory server with ZFS deduplication: can zram help?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, deduplication

Is it a good idea to use compressed memory if people want to save on expensive RAM when using ZFS with deduplication?

Answer (score 0):

That's the [second question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704194/can-swap-help-a-low-memory-zfs-server) where you ask

> I want to build a storage server that uses fast RAM, but don't have RAM.

Remember **why** you need that RAM: to avoid having to do everything on the SSD itself, and to avoid having to compute things twice because it doesn't fit  in your RAM.

If compressing and uncompressing on the fly was no problem, so would be re-calculating hashes. Your approach, again, ignores *why* you want much RAM in a storage server that does ZFS deduplication. Yes, zram will *potentially* allow you to do more with the same amount of RAM, but ZFS itself already offers compression, which you probably enabled before you tried to introduce deduplication. Because compressed data cannot be easily further compressed, zram will not be able to use less RAM for your ZFS block data. It will also not be able to compress a tree structure of hashes, that having almost maximal entropy (you might want to read up on how deduplication and zram work!). So, again, nope. You need more RAM. Why is that a problem, even? You're running a seriously large storage cluster if you need 512 GB RAM.

And, again, as last time, you're not offering any system size insight, although I did ask for that.